# How to get jQuery click event after append in change event handler

Tags: jquery, events

I have the following document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="alert"></div>
    <input type="text" id="input"></br>
    <span id="span">Span</span>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#input').on('change', function() {
            console.log('change');
            $('#alert').append('<div>An alert</div>');
        });
        $('#span').on('click', function() {
            console.log('click');
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Click on the span and the click event handler runs.

Change the input and the change event handler runs.

Change the input and click on the span (without otherwise leaving the input - e.g. no tab out and no click elsewhere) and the change event handler runs but the click event handler does not run.

If I remove the append from the change event handler, then change the input and click on the span, both event handlers run, so the append is interfering with the click event somehow.

How can I get the click event to fire after the change event handler appends the elements?

This is minimal code to elicit the problem. In the real case there are multiple inputs and the span is styled to look and behave like a button. The change event handlers on the inputs validate the values, adding an alert if they are invalid. Commonly, inputs are changed without clicking the span/button but editing an input then clicking the span/button while input focus is still on an input is possible, in which case I want both event handlers to run.

On further investigation, I see that the problem is in how events are generated.

Per DOM Level-2: The click event occurs when the pointing device button is clicked over an element. A click is defined as a mousedown and mouseup over the same screen location. The sequence of these events is:

```
mousedown
mouseup
click
```

Without the 'append' in the change event handler, when I edit the input then click on the span I see:

1. mousedown on span
2. change on input
3. mouseup on span
4. click on span

But, with the append in the change event handler I see:

1. mousedown on span
2. change on input
3. mouseup on input

In the latter case, the mousedown and mouseup events have the same coordinates (if I am careful not to move the mouse while clicking): they are both coordinates within the bounds of the span element and outside the input element. None the less, in Firefox and Chrome the mouseup is associated with the input element rather than the span element.

So, my question becomes: why is the mouseup event associated with the input element rather than the span element, when its coordinates are within the bounds of the span element and not within the bounds of the input element?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/4zx8rm7c/ but it's not 100% clear what you expect it to do. The code does exactly what it should as it is written. In other words your explanation is not very clear

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the terminology to say it clearly. If I edit the content of the input box then click on the span without otherwise leaving the input box, I expect both the change and click events, but I only see the change event. I am working with Firefox 34.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a number of workarounds to deal with this issue. It totally depends on the UI presentation. Depending on the design you can think of other workarounds as well. As of now I can think of three things which can be done to deal with the issue:

1. Give your alert div a height and make it vertically scroll-able. Doing this will prevent your span's position change and would trigger both the events. e.g

   ```
    <div id="alert" style="height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;"></div>
   ```
2. Or you can change your javascript a little to meet your purpose. Below is the code snippet (comments amended) with changes to meet your need.

   ```
   $(function() {
       var isMouseDownOnSpan = 0;  // flag variable added to track whether user clicked on the span.
       $('#input').on('change', function() {
           console.log('change');
           $('#alert').append('<div>An alert</div>');
           // If user tries to click on the span then trigger the click event manually.
           if(isMouseDownOnSpan){
               $('#span').trigger('click');                
           }
       });

       // Bind mousedown event and set the flag value true. This ensures that the user clicked on the span.
       $('#span').on('mousedown', function(e) {
           isMouseDownOnSpan = 1;
       });

       $('#span').on('click', function() {
           isMouseDownOnSpan = 0; // Reset flag value once the click event is fired.
           console.log('click');
       });
     });
   ```
3. OR else none of the above suits you then you can design your span and give it certain width and height such that the user's mouse is within the span boundaries even after the alert div is appended. I know this can't be a permanent solution but still it can minimize the changes of error in real life scenarios. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I saved your code and ran in a browser and it works. why do you think it does not? are you checking the console output?

Comment: Yes - I check the console output. When I change the input contents then click on the span I see the log from the change event handler but nothing from the click event handler. If I remove the append from the change event handler and do the same thing, then I see the logs from both event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

In your change event handler add a $('#span').click()

```
$(function() {
    $('#input').on('change', function() {
        console.log('change');
        $('#alert').append('<div>An alert</div>');
        $('#span').click();
    });
    $('#span').on('click', function() {
        console.log('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to do that because in the real case there are multiple inputs and there can be a change to an input without a click on the span. For example, if one edits the input then tabs out or clicks elsewhere than the span.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem is:

When I add to the div, the document layout changes. I put the cursor over the span and press the left mouse button. This causes the input to lose focus, triggering the change event. The change event handler appends a div to the #alert div. This pushes everything below it down the screen. Then I release the mouse button, without having moved it. But the mouse is no longer over the span - it is now over the input, due to the changed layout, so the mouseup event has the input as its target, not the span.

Even though the mouse hasn't moved, the screen layout has changed so the mouse has left the span and entered the input. The span sees a mousedown with no mouseup, so no click. The input sees a mouseup with no mousedown, so no click there either.

My mistake was to think that because I hadn't moved the mouse, the mouse should still be over the span.

If I put the alert div after the span, then editing the input and clicking the span works as expected, but this isn't the screen layout I want.

I guess if I leave the alert div at the top, what I need to do in the change event handler is add the message to the alert div, which will move the span down, then move the mouse down so it is still over the span. Then, when the user releases the mouse button it will still be over the span and the span may (I hope) receive a click event.

Answer (score -2):

```js
     $(function() {
            $('#input').on('change', function() {
                console.log('change');
                $('#alert').append('An alert', function(){
                      $('#span').on('click', function() {
                         console.log('click');
                      });
                });
            });
            $('#span').on('click', function() {
                console.log('click');
            });
        });
```

Comment: this will add compunded click handlers on `#span`

Comment: just in case somebody stumbles upon this. This is NOT good code. the original on event is going to capture the click event. Adding duplicate events on the same span will not solve his problem and is not a good approach.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't solve my problem. I don't see additional click event handlers executing on subsequent click events on the span, so I guess the second argument to append is never called, though it is added to the div, as text.