# javascript event handlers list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events

I am trying to prioritize click event in case two events click and change are fired.

I have a global function similar to "ValidateOnChange" and "ValidateOnClick" to validate input of text box on change and on click event.

Enter some text, it shows up error message. Then try to input correct value and click the Submit button, the error vanishes and this makes user to click the button twice. Here I am trying to fix this double click.

Here is mock up code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Enter any string:</div>
    <div><input type="text"  id="txtInput" ></input></div>
    <div id="divError" style="color: red; display: none;">Please enter 0</div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnSubmit" ></input>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mouseevent_var = null;
        function ValidateOnChange(e) {
            var input = $('#txtInput').val();
            if (input == '0') {
                $('#divError').hide();
            } else {
                $('#divError').show();
            }
        }

        function ValidateOnClick(e){
            alert("Hurray!!! You got it right!");
        }

        $('#txtInput').mousedown(function (e) {
            mouseevent_var = e;
        });

      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
            ValidateOnClick(e);
        });

        $('#txtInput').change(function(e){
            ValidateOnChange(e);
        });

        //User don't want error when they are typing in.
        //$('#txtInput').keyup(function() {
            //$('#txtInput').trigger("change");
        //});
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The keyup event seemed to be solution but users don't want the error to popup when they are typing in.

Is there any way to list all the triggered events so that I could filter "mousedown" and "mouseup" events for submit button? Or is there any alternative way to prioritize click event ?

Comment: If you're using html5 you could use the `oninput` / `input`  event... I'm not sure what sort of validation you want to do as your functions don't seem to be doing or validating anything. Depending on the validation, different event handlers can be used for a smoother operation. Also, I don't see how this is a `asp.net` related question.

Comment: I am not getting your requirement. Can you please explain what you want to accomplish by above code?

Comment: Also you can do `$('#divError').toggle(input != '0');`

Answer (score 0):

There can be many alternatives depending on the situations. I have made few minor changes to avoid the double click issue (comments amended). Basically we need to bind the mousedown event on the button object. There we will set a temporary flag variable to true. In the same time if input's change event gets fired then you can skip the checking if the temporary flag variable is true. Reason behind the double click for triggering the button's click event is better explained here:  [How to get jQuery click event after append in change event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629887/how-to-get-jquery-click-event-after-append-in-change-event-handler/28718099#28718099)

Your updated js code below:

```
var mouseevent_var = false;
    function ValidateOnChange(e) {
        // Skip validation if the change event is fired due to user's click on submit button
        if(mouseevent_var){ return false; }

        var input = $('#txtInput').val();
        if (input == 0) {
            $('#divError').hide();
        } else {
            $('#divError').show();
        }
    }

    function ValidateOnClick(e){
        mouseevent_var = false;    // Reset mouseevent_var to false
        alert("Hurray!!! You got it right!");
    }

    $('#btnSubmit').mousedown(function (e) {
        mouseevent_var = true;
    });

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
        ValidateOnClick(e);
    });

    $('#txtInput').change(function(e){
        ValidateOnChange(e);
    });

    //User don't want error when they are typing in.
    //$('#txtInput').keyup(function() {
        //$('#txtInput').trigger("change");
    //});
  });
```

The above code is just a fix as per your need. But there are other better alternatives too. Ideally you should not have two different validation functions for validating same fields on different events. You must think of managing it with a single function.